Heating a Single Water Molecule
From my understanding, phase changes break/form bonds between molecules of the same substance. Assuming this is in a vessel at 1atm of inert gas, if I have one molecule of water with no bonds to other water molecules, what state of matter would it be? If there are no bonds to form/break, would its heat curve be smooth? I know energy is stored in bonds, so would the water molecule even heat up?

What do you mean by "smooth heat curve"?

One molecule is not enough to be qualified as a phase. One needs a macroscopic number of molecules.

As the phase state is macroscopic phenomena, it does not make much sense to talk about a state of a single molecule. If you must, that consider it being in the gaseous state.
Speaking of heating of a single molecule does not make much sense either, as temperature is another macroscopic parameter. At the given temperature, molecules can have a wide range of kinetic energies. At the same time, for the given kinetic energy, molecules can belong to systems with a wide range of possible temperatures.
So even at constant temperature, the kinetic energy of a molecule widely changes at every collision. While temperature changes just change its mean kinetic energy over the time.
A molecule stores energy in form of translation, rotation and vibration energy, at high temperature also as an electron excitation energy.
